# The public folder of Laravel, using Laravel just for one website and potential conflicts?

Tags: php, laravel

On my windows server we host dozens of websites and web apps. We use WAMP.

I am learning about Laravel and want to use it for just website. According to this guide (http://codehappy.daylerees.com/project-structure) which is talking me through the project structure, "public is the directory that you must point your web server to".

So if I host the site on wamp/www/projects/example_site

And use a vhost to rename to point www.examplesite.com to the example_site folder, **can I use example_site are the public folder?** And will this cause any conflicts with my other projects on the parent folders? It seems like Laravel does things to session storage and other important things and it's extremely important the other sites aren't affected since they get millions of hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a better idea to include the project files somewhere else on the server, outside of the web directory and simply direct the webserver to the relevant public folder using the virtual host configuration:

For example, the various Laravel installations could go into folders:

```
C:/wamp/projects/site1
C:/wamp/projects/site2
C:/wamp/projects/site3
```

then simply configure the virtual hosts in apache like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/projects/site1/public
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/projects/site2/public
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site3.com
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/projects/site3/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could locate your laravel installation outside of the "projects" folder, for example at "wamp/www/laravel", and then create a symlink at "wamp/www/projects/laravel" that points to "wamp/www/laravel/public".

Symlink Reference:  http://nareshkhokhani.blogspot.com/2008/05/virtual-directory-in-wamp-using.html

Comment: The problem is that the projects folder is exposed to the world wide web because all the folders in it are websites/webapps

Comment: I understand now.  I have updated my answer to reflect my new suggestion.